# Local Server not accessible on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, fedora

My Internet company set up a local server, where different files are hosted. I can download files at much higher speed from there. But for some reason, the server is not accessible from Ubuntu 13.10 I am using, or Fedora 19. So the problem should be Linux specific.

N.B. It is perfectly accessible from windows. It is not accessible via router too. Probably they are using some IP Address checking, which can't be done via router.

Comment: What do you mean by "not accessible"? Does the server reply to pings? How do you access the server, via Samba, ftp, http?

Comment: It is not accessible via ping, I access it using browser, So its on port 80/http

Comment: If it's not accessibe via ping, it is a routing problem, not an authentication problem. Can you ping anything at all from you Ubuntu machine?

Comment: yes I can ping other servers; let's say www.google.com, both from Ubuntu and Fedora

Comment: can you post the output of ifconfig, route -n, and tell us the IP address of your server?

Comment: What's the exact message you see in your browser?

Comment: Problem solved, though in a peculiar way. I put the IP Address from traceroute directly in browser & the server opened its file directory & that's good enough for me.

Comment: @rafee if this solves your problem, please add a new "answer" to your own question and mark it as *accepted*. having to read through an answer and all it's comments is a bit disappointing to only discover, that there really is no problem needed any more.

Comment: But its very specific, what should I put on answer?

Comment: And to be honest, It didn't solve my whole problem. But I don't want to pursue it any more. I am satisfied with partial solution.

Comment: If you can access the server by IP address but not by name, it sounds likely that you have a DNS problem.

Comment: Add these two lines (as sudo) to your /etc/resolv.conf file: nameserver 8.8.8.8       nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: You are referring to Google dns. As its a local address, its valid inside my Local connection, not anywhere else. So I don't think Google DNS is going to work

Comment: Are `/etc/resolv.conf` the same on both (the Fedora and ubuntu) systems?